# exception thrown when debug single stepping vs2017

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to single step (F10/F11) through my code, but it doesn't work. It always throws a "Access violation writing location 0x0000" exception from within ntdll.dll.

When running the program straight it works fine. The exception is only thrown when single stepping. It doesn't matter where in the code the single step occurs I can place a BP at random somewhere in the code, run the program to the BP and then single step from the BP. That hit's the exception.

When starting the program in single step (F10) I can't even execute the first statement.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: When disabling native code debugging it works. However without native code debugging I can't debug unmanaged code anymore. I chalk this up to an actual problem in vs2017. I've no idea what the reason can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When disabling native code debugging it works. However without native code debugging you can't debug unmanaged code anymore.
That makes work a bit akward. When debugging code within a unmanaged DLL you have to enable "native code debugging" set the BP inside the DLL code. Single stepping within the DLL works. Once you're done and go back to managed code you have to disable "native code debugging".
Weird.

Comment: ,Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members.